# Changing class combinations based on multiple conditions

Tags: html, css, angularjs, validation, ng-class

I have few style classes defined in my style sheet as like the following:

```
.left-align{
  /* some styles here */
}
.right-align{
  /* some styles here */
}
.validate-error{
  /* some styles here */
}
```

Based on the type of data in the class I need to align the content left or right, and also I wanted to call a method which will validate my data in the control, if validation fails need to append the `validate-error` class as well to the `ng-class`. I gone through different SO threads and other articles and QA sites that titled as *multiple conditions in `ng-class`* but nothing found working in my scenario, I have tried the following based on the references:

```
ng-class="{!vm.validate()?'validate-error': vm.isNumericField?'right-align':'left-align'}"
```

But this will not align the content to the right even `isNumericField` is true when `validate()` returns false.

In short, I need to add `left-align` or `right-align` depends on the `isNumericField` property and also `validate-error` if `validate()` returns false.

```
 "isNumericField?{'left-align':'right-align'} + 'validate-error':validate()"
```

Please anyone let me know if there any way to achieve this:

Comment: Can't use simple if loop to  get the attribute class  and change it? something like : if ($scope.isNumericField)
      $scope.class = "left-align"; else $scope.class = "right-align";

Comment: @HemaNandagopal: fine, as of now I'm able to toggle two classes, But I need to find a way to add the second class if `validate()` method returns false. as a result am expecting `ng-class="right-align validate-error"`

Comment: In that case you can combine both the classes,$scope.class=" right-align validate-error";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify "map" of class names to boolean values:

```
ng-class="{'validate-error': !vm.validate(), 'right-align': vm.isNumericField, 'left-align': !vm.isNumericField}"
```